# How to extract a hidden file in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, steganography

I'm trying to hide a file inside of a file and then take the hidden file back out and look at it.

I'm hiding the file just fine. However, I need to extract the file. I combine two byte arrays with a third in the middle for the separator. I'm not able to extract the whole file.

```kotlin
import java.io.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val original = args[0]
    val hidden = args[1]
    var newFile: String? = null
    if(args.size == 3)
        newFile = args[2]

    //if its null I extract the file
    if(newFile == null){
        val originalFile = File(original)
        val parts = originalFile.readBytes().toString().split("777777")
        val bytes = parts.last().toByteArray()
        val hiddenFile = File(hidden)
        hiddenFile.writeBytes(bytes)
        println("$hiddenFile is unhidden")
        return
    }

    //hide the file
    val originalBytes = File(original).readBytes()
    val hiddenBytes = File(hidden).readBytes()
    val file = File(newFile!!)
    val separator = "777777".toByteArray()
    file.writeBytes(originalBytes + separator + hiddenBytes)
    println("$newFile is created")
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in broad terms what the code is intended to do? (It appears to have nothing to do with [hidden files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) in the usual sense…)

Comment: I'm taking file A and B and creating C with them. They are separated with a separator byte array in the middle of C. Then I take C and extract B to create D. The hidden file. @gidds

Comment: In broad terms. Okay. I'm trying to hide a file inside of a file and then take the hidden file back out and look at it.

Comment: Your extraction code splits on `777777` but then only ever uses the first element of the split array. But it looks like you originally stored the hidden data after the delimiter.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo you were right. However, it would've extracted the original file instead. I changed it and it still doesn't work. But thank you so much.

Comment: What is the result you get? Do you get back your file, but corrupted? My guess would be the string conversion part, not every byte array can be meaningfully converted to a string,  it is a lossy operation in general

Comment: @TamasHegedus yes I get a corrupted file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a corrupted file, that is most probably happening because the intermediate String conversion. When decoding a byte array to a string, and then re-encoding it into a byte array, you won't get back the same array with most encoding schemes.

To mitigate this problem, I would skip the string conversion entirely. You can use Google's Guava library to find your pattern in a byte array, using the [`Bytes.indexOf`](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Bytes.html) function.

Something like this:

```
import java.io.*
import com.google.common.primitives.Bytes

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val original = args[0]
    val hidden = args[1]
    var newFile: String? = null
    if(args.size == 3)
        newFile = args[2]
    val separator = "777777".toByteArray()
    val originalBytes = File(original).readBytes()

    //if its null I extract the file
    if(newFile == null){
        val separatorIndex = Bytes.indexOf(originalBytes , separator)
        val bytes = originalBytes.sliceArray(separatorIndex + pattern.size..fileData.size - 1)
        val hiddenFile = File(hidden)
        hiddenFile.writeBytes(bytes)
        println("$hiddenFile is unhidden")
        return
    }

    //hide the file
    val hiddenBytes = File(hidden).readBytes()
    val file = File(newFile!!)
    file.writeBytes(originalBytes + separator + hiddenBytes)
    println("$newFile is created")
}
```